# how to hide associated products in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have created the configurable product and also associated products with it but I don't want to show those associated products to show on frontend.
So anyone can tell me how to hide the associated products from frontend.

[here is the link to how to add the configurable products.](http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the associated simple products from frontend, you just need to change the visibility to "Not Visible Individually"

To change the visibility,in the admin panel, go to Catalog->Manage products->Edit that particular product.

In the visibility dropdown, select "Not Visible Individually". That particular product will not be displayed on frontend.